# When checkbox is checked right text from text box to database

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a dynamic list of questions generated from a database.

I get my questions listed with a textbox and checkbox, I would like to have the text from the text box written to the database in a separate table when the check box it checked.

I can write the question to the database but with no answer from the text box.

the code below generates my list.

```
                    com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Task] FROM Debrief_Tasks WHERE [Current] = TRUE AND [Group] = 4", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
                    datareader = com.ExecuteReader();

                    int e = 1;

                    while (datareader.Read())
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            string Task = datareader.GetString(0);

                            Label taskLable = new Label();
                            taskLable.Text = Task;
                            taskLable.AutoSize = true;
                            taskLable.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
                            TextBox nameTextBox = new TextBox();
                            nameTextBox.Name = ToString();
                            nameTextBox.AutoSize = true;
                            nameTextBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
                            nameTextBox.Padding = new Padding(1);
                            nameTextBoxes.Add(nameTextBox);
                            CheckBox completeCheckBox = new CheckBox();
                            completeCheckBox.Name = Task.ToString();
                            completeCheckBox.AutoSize = true;
                            completeCheckBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
                            completeCheckBox.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                            completeCheckBox.Padding = new Padding(1);
                            completeCheckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(completeCheckBox_CheckedChanged);
                            completeCheckBoxes.Add(completeCheckBox);


                            tableLayoutPanel5.RowCount = e + 2;
                            tableLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(taskLable, 0, e + 1);
                            tableLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(nameTextBox, 1, e + 1);
                            tableLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(completeCheckBox, 2, e + 1);
                            i++;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void completeCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;



        if (checkBox.Checked)
        {

            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Debrief ([Debrief_Date], [Task], [DoneName]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Today.Date));
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", Convert.ToString(checkBox.Name)));
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", ***Convert.ToString(checkBox.Name***)));


            OleDbDataReader datareader = com.ExecuteReader();
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

I know my last sql input is the same as the other but this is the only way I can get it to run.

Any ideas how to link the relevant text box to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Dictionary<CheckBox, TextBox>` to your code which will hold the references to related `CheckBoxes` and `TextBoxes`, something like this:

create the dictionary within the class scope:

```
Dictionary<CheckBox, TextBox> pairs = new Dictionary<CheckBox, TextBox>();
```

and in the code add the code that inserts each CheckBox-TextBox pair into the `Dictionary` after they are both created:

```
pairs.Add(completeCheckBox,nameTextBox);
```

And in the `completeCheckBox_CheckedChanged` retrieve the `TextBox` using the `CheckBox` reference

```
TextBox associatedTextBox = null;
pairs.TryGetValue(checkBox, out associatedTextBox);
```

and use `associatedTextBox.Text` for database storing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var textBoxValue = ((TextBox)checkBox.Parent
    .Controls[checkBox.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(checkBox) - 2]).Text;
```

Basically, you would use the checkbox to get the parent control container, then reference the textbox in the collection, by using it's relative position to the checkbox.

Note that this an easy approach as far as you have a simple and consistent page design. If you have a dynamic structure per question or the relative path is too complex, I would also recommend using Nikola's approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this code inside the if (checkbox.Checked) condition...

```
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Debrief ([Debrief_Date], [Task], [DoneName]) VALUES (@Debrief_Date, @Task, @DoneName)", Program.DB_CONNECTION);

com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Debrief_Date", OledbType.DateTime)).Value = DateTime.Today.Date;
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Task", OledbType.VarChar, 30)).Value = checkBox.Text;
com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DoneName", OledbType.VarChar, 30)).Value = checkBox.Text;

Program.DB_CONNECTION.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That was just a test code. Just align the dbtypes and the length with what you have in your database. I hope that works. ;)